# Python modules not found in Sublime IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimetext, ubuntu-18.04

I am using Sublime IDE for development. When I'm building my code on Sublime on Ubuntu 18.04, it gives me an error saying:

> ImportError: No module named numpy

I have installed numpy on my system and it works just fine when I run it on the terminal.

How do I get the code to build successfully on Sublime itself?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds that your interpreter set in sublime text is different from the one you're using to run the code in the console.
Make sure you're using the same one, either by setting it in sublime or by simply installing the relevant packages for the one used in sublime.
Personally I use PyCharm, but I guess sublime is using the default python interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Oleg said, the interpreter on my terminal and on Sublime were different.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103987/how-to-change-python-version-in-sublime-ubuntu-18

Used the above link to change the default interpreter for Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens when you have installed numpy in a different version of Python. Like you are using Python3 but numpy is installed in Python2. So Try to reinstall numpy by specifying the Python version.
Try:

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```

this will install numpy using Python3 and you will be able to use it in your IDE.

Comment: I have numpy installed to Python3 and my file also has extension .py3, yet I'm getting this error.

`pip3 install numpy`

is the command I used to install numpy.